# Counting selections of $12$ chocolates selected from $10$ milk chocolates, $10$ dark chocolates, and $1$ fat-free chocolate

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I want to choose $12$ chocolates from $3$ different varieties:

- $10$ milk chocolates,
- $10$ dark chocolates, and
- $1$ fat-free chocolate

In how many ways can I do this?
I tried
$$\frac{_{21}P_{12}}{10!\cdot10!}=\frac{21!}{9!\cdot10!\cdot10!}$$
($10!\cdot10!$ account for repetitions)

which apparently isn't correct.

Comment: I am assuming that the milk chocolates are considered indisinguishable from each other, so that if (for example) you choose exactly 5 milk chocolates, it won't matter **which** 5 of the 10 total milk chocolates that you choose.  Based on this assumption, I would divide the problem into two cases: case 1: the fat free chocolate is part of your selection of 12 chocolates and case 2: the fat free chocolate is not selected.

Comment: Re my previous comment, my assumption may be inaccurate: it depends on the *intent* of the question.  You can **not** attack this question without first determining (e.g. from your teacher) whether the assumption that I made is accurate.

Comment: Note: the reason that I made this assumption is that the problem becomes **trivial** otherwise.  That is, if my assumption is wrong then the answer must be ${}_{12}C_{21} = \frac{21!}{12!9!}.$

Comment: Also, it is good that you showed your work, it demonstrates where you are confused.  You are misunderstanding how to enumerate the cases, so you need to develop your intuition.  I recommend pretending that there were only 3 milk chocolates, and only 3 dark chocolates, and that you wanted to enumerate the total number of *different* ways of selecting 3 chocolates from the 7.  **Actually** count them **manually**.  Then try to come up with a formula that **agrees with your manual count.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m$, $d$, and $f$ be, respectively, the number of milk, dark, and fat-free chocolates.  Then we want to find the number of solutions of the equation 
$$m + d + f = 12$$
in the nonnegative integers subject to the constraints that $m \leq 10$, $d \leq 10$, and $f \leq 1$.

The constraint $f \leq 1$ is best handled, as @user2661923 suggested in the comments, by considering two cases, depending on whether the selection includes a fat-free chocolate.

**Case 1:**  The fat-free chocolate is not selected.

Since the fat-free chocolate is not selected, $f = 0$, so we must find the number of solutions of the equation 
$$m + d = 12$$ 
in the nonnegative integers subject to the constraints $m \leq 10$, $d \leq 10$.  Notice that choosing how many milk chocolates are selected determines how many dark chocolates are selected.  Since $d \leq 10$, at least how many milk chocolates must be selected?  At most how many milk chocolates may be selected?

> $2 \leq m \leq 10 \implies 9$ solutions

**Case 2:** The fat-free chocolate is selected.

Since the fat-free chocolate is selected, $f = 1$, so we must find the number of solutions of the equation 
$$m + d = 11$$
in the nonnegative integers subject to the constraints $m \leq 10$, $d \leq 10$.  Again, choosing how many milk chocolates are selected determines how many dark chocolates are selected.  Since $d \leq 10$, at least how many milk chocolates must be selected?  At most how many milk chocolates may be selected?

> $1 \leq m \leq 10 \implies 10$ solutions

**Total:** The two cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, so the total can be found by adding the results of the two cases.

*What was wrong with your approach?*

You selected $12$ items but divided by $10!10!$.  However, $10 + 10 = 20 > 12$.  The number of distinguishable ways six milk chocolates, five dark chocolates, and one fat-free chocolate can be selected is 
$$\binom{12}{6}\binom{6}{5}\binom{1}{1} = \frac{12!}{6!6!} \cdot \frac{6!}{5!1!} \cdot \frac{1!}{1!0!} = \frac{12!}{6!5!1!}$$
where we choose six positions in the sequence of twelve selections for the milk chocolates, five of the remaining six positions for the dark chocolates, and fill the remaining position with the fat-free chocolate.  Notice that $6 + 5 + 1 = 12$.

Since you would have to list all the possible selections in order to do the problem in this way, it is not an efficient approach to the problem of counting how many selections there are.

Comment: I like N. F. Taussig's answer, which *guides* the OP, **especially** since the answer addressed where the OP went wrong.  However, I still criticize that portion of the answer.  The OP's posting demonstrates sufficient confusion that he needs to develop his intuition "from scratch," by *manually dissecting* simpler cases, as I recommended in my previous comment.  I would argue that for the OP, this will be a more productive approach than attempting to understand the **What was wrong...** portion of N.F. Taussig's answer.